# Aggregate dictionary results across python objects

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I know that without this the way I would probably go about is just a bunch of for loops but I thought it must be possible to do it easier. I have a folder full of unorganized non-unified sets of data and I am writing a python script to parse it and analyse some results. The way I went about it is to parse the heaps of data by some of their characteristics and metrics into a class defined object - each data set an object - so in the end I will have an array of objects of the same class just filled with different data.

The important stuff in each object is stored in lists. E.g.:

```
data = {
    'attribute_1': true,
    'attribute_2': false,
    'attribute_1_speed': 25.3,
    'attribute_2_speed': null
}
```

So in the end I have x objects each with the same dictionary, is there maybe an existing function that could iterate them and create a hash map of sorts / aggregation of the values to see the distributions of true/false values per attribute, maybe means and averages for the numerical values?

Comment: Please include your full script as well as your current and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not providing your implementation I wrote a script which I believe achieves the aggregation you need. My implementation assumes that your objects have only one attribute (which is the dictionary `data`). If this is not the case and your objects have attributes similar to the keys of your dictionary, then the implementation would be even simpler:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

data = {
    'a1': True,
    'a2': False,
    'a1_speed': 25.3,
    'a2_speed': None
}
x,y,z = X(data),X(data),X(data)

object_list = []
object_list.append(x)
object_list.append(z)
object_list.append(y)

object_dict = {id(x): x.data['a1'] for x in object_list}
aggregation_dict ={}

for i in object_dict.keys():
    if object_dict[i] in aggregation_dict.keys():
        aggregation_dict[object_dict[i]] += 1
    else:
        aggregation_dict[object_dict[i]] = 1

print(object_dict)
print(aggregation_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{140254557973760: True, 140254557754128: True, 140254557753984: True}
{True: 3}
```

The function `id` creates random keys used to build the `object_dict`. For loop checks if the specific field (I chose to aggregate data according to `a1` but obviously you can change that to whatever you want) already exists in the aggregation dictionary, `aggregation_dict`, and if it does, increment the value by one.